# LiveData Transformations with Flow

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

Has I read more about Flow I'm starting to think that you can replace MutableLiveData switchMap pattern with something similar with flow.

You can replace LiveData observation with flow by implementing something like [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-singleliveevent-redux-with-kotlin-flow-b755c70bb055) but I'm unable to imagine how to replace the switchMap part.

By switchMap pattern I mean this:

```
val mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<SomeClass> = MutableLiveData()
val liveData: LiveData<SomeOtherClass> = mutableLiveData
    .switchMap {
       //call to repo
    }
```

Is there anything equivalent or am I missing out something completely? Or even thinking about flow completely the wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent is [`Flow.flatMapLatest((T) -> Flow<R>)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html). They actually removed the. `Flow.switchMap` function in favour of a few new `mapLatest` functions.

However this has been marked as experimental for now so use it with caution.

Comment: I see! Found this after reading your answer - https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines?hl=pt#11